# jQuery loads on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

**EDIT:** It looks like for whatever reason my assets are not loading.  My javascript is returning me 404 errors on the server.

**ORIGINAL:** I know jQuery loads when I run the app on my localhost because; 1. my app works, and 2. the following code also tells me jQuery is loading when the page loads.

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
  // jQuery is loaded => print the version
  alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
```

The problem is as soon as I push it to Heroku, jQuery doesn't work.  The above code doesn't run anymore, and when I try to run `$.post( "/time_records", {current_time: current_time});` i get the following error; `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

When I run my Bundler on Heroku it says `Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)`

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Thanks to @Maxime for pointing me in the right direction.)

According to the **Heroku Rails Support** page, as a final task in the compilation phase, the `assets:precompile` Rake task is executed.  If you have a `assets:precompile` Rake task defined, and don’t have a `public/assets/manifest-*.json` file. This will compile all assets and put them in your public directory. *If this asset compilation fails, the deploy will fail as well.*

My deploy was not failing, so I thought this step was happening smoothly, but when I checked the logs it said

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (2.49s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
-----> WARNINGS:
       Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
```

It turns out that without the inclusion of the `rails_12factor gem` the pages were not able to find the assets properly, and returning 404 errors.  The fix was simple, add the following to your GemFile;

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're putting your application online on Heroku, check if the Javascript file doesn't return a **404 HTTP error** online. If it does, jQuery will never be loaded...
It can be due to severals errors in your configuration (absolute filepath from your local configuration or whatever)

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  You were right, the javascript is returning a 404.  I'm still trying to figure out how to fix this though.  All my configurations are still default from generation.

Comment: Alas, my issue is not resolved, we just narrowed down the problem.